# Sort 2D array in ascending order

Tags: java, arrays

```
        class arrayDemo {

            static void sort2D(int[][] B) {

             boolean swap = true;
             int oy=0;
             int temp=0;

             for(int ox=0;ox<B.length;ox++){
                 while(oy<B[ox].length) {
                     while(swap) {
                     swap = false;
                         for(int ix=0;ix<B.length;ix++) {
                             for(int iy=0;iy<B[ix].length;iy++) {
                                     if(B[ox][oy]<B[ix][iy]) {
                                     temp = B[ix][iy];
                                     B[ix][iy] = B[ox][oy];
                                     B[ox][oy] = temp;
                                     swap = true;
                                     }
                                 }
                             }           
                     }
                 oy++; 
                 }
             } 
             for(int row=0;row<B.length;row++)
             for(int col=0;col<B[row].length;col++)
             System.out.println(B[row][col]);
             }

public static void main(String...S) {

     int y[][] = {{10,20,0,30},{10,5,8},{3,9,8,7},{2,3}};
     sort2D(y);
}    
}
```

I am trying to sort a 2D array in ascending order.

Input: {{10,20,0,30},{10,5,8},{3,9,8,7},{2,3}}; 
Output: 30,20,10,10,9,8,8,7,5,3,0,2,3

Can someone help me know what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Is this homework? Can you use the standard JDK utilities?

Comment: Yes, this is an assignment. I have to develop my own logic, cannot use JDK utilities.

Comment: When I run that code I get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: I have made some more changes to the code, now it's running, but i am unable to edit the code i just posted. Is there an optiuon that I could post my updated code?

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing elements that are not in the same row or column. Each sub-array should be sorted individually. You might want to reconsider this line `if (B[ox][oy] < B[ix][iy])`.

Comment: i just updated my code, taking care of my previous mistakes. Now i am getting an output, but not in proper order. Please take a look.

Comment: The basic structure of the method should be for(row = 0; row < b.length, row++) { sort(b[row]) }. I'll leave the sorting of each row to you.

Answer (score 0):

That code has a number of problems.

1. It throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. This is because all for loop tests test against `B.length`, which is not correct for inner arrays.
2. You are comparing every pair of elements, but some pairs are the reverse of other pairs, and the reverse pairs should not be tested. You need to limit the scope of your inner set of `for` loops, by starting at a different index.

To fix all these problems, the path of least resistance is to dump the 2D array into a 1D array and sort that, which is much easier.

Here is code that has been tested and shown to work:

```
static void sort2D(int[][] B) {

        int count = 0;
        for (int[] is : B)
            for (int i : is)
                count++;
        int[] A = new int[count];
        count = 0;
        for (int[] is : B)
            for (int i : is)
                A[count++] = i;

        int temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
            for (int j = i + 1; j < A.length; j++)
                if (A[i] > A[j]) {
                    temp = A[i];
                    A[i] = A[j];
                    A[j] = temp;
                }
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
                System.out.print(A[i] + ",");

}
```

Comment: Please take a look at my new code, it addresses all the errors you just pointed. Thanks for responding.